# Cannot switch to monitor from laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a monitor that i'm using with my laptop. The problem is it doesn't display after i select it from Displays and hit Apply (I want to show image only on the monitor, not the built-in display). Only the mouse is showing and everything is black. I didn't have this problem with my old laptop. Also Windows 10 (i'm dual-booting) displays it with no problem. I'm looking to show the image only on the monitor, not on laptop's built-in display. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. If it does help, i had some problems finding the 1600x900 resolution for displaying for the built-in display, but i managed to add it using 'xrandr' command, and set it for automatically start with ubuntu in the ~/.profile (insterted the two commands there). So what's the problem? Thanks and have a nice day!

[image: Setting applied for the external monitor]

**EDIT:** After i've installed the nVidia driver, now the BenQ monitor doesn't appear any more. What should i do next? Thanks!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/627320/put-external-monitor-on-the-left

Comment: select Built-in display -> tean on General options

Comment: what do you mean 'tean on General options' ? I want to show image only on the external display, not the built-in display.

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/Hkeib2lCD0WxZvtG/null    this

Comment: so what should i do on General after selecting the built-in display?

Comment: select laptop display and set as primary

Comment: but i want to use only the benq monitor.

Comment: now remove monitor

Comment: i don't understand. why should i remove the monitor? i want to use it as primary display, to show image on it, not the built-in display

Comment: oh sorry it's my bad. 1min plz

Comment: what is you'r laptop model

Comment: Acer Aspire VN7-593G

Comment: press fn + F5 try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attached a picture with the NVidia driver as it is installed from the Additional Drivers. Does this good or should i install another version?

[image: NVidia driver's settings]

**EDIT #1:** I downloaded the latest driver from NVIDIA website. It's a .run file. When i try to install it, i get the following error:

[image: NVIDIA driver installation error]

**EDIT #2:** Here is the answer that actually worked for me:

1. disable secure boot
2. select another driver that is not from nvidia in
       the additional drivers
3. restart
4. sudo apt purge nvidia*
5. sudo
       add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
6. sudo apt update
7. go to
       additional drivers select the nvidia binary driver (proprietary)
8. restart

Now i have all the options inside NVIDIA X Server Settings and my secondary monitor works.

Comment: go to settings configuration and select your monitor set primary

Comment: check nvidia driver version and try to fix it. ithink you have a driver's issue

Comment: i cannot select my display from settings since it's not listed. When i'm using the installed nvidia driver my monitor isn't shown. I downloaded the latest driver from NVIDIA website, but i cannot install it, i get an error ('You appear to be running an X server...").. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: go to additional drivers and select nvidia binary driver more information please check this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeWTSprpq1M (Install Nvidia Driver on Ubuntu 16.04 (GUI Method for Beginners)).

Comment: you can understand what is x server

Comment: I will switch again to the nvidia binary driver then will install the nvidia driver again. I will get back after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: off laptop screen and apply]

off laptop screen and apply. it is work for me
or you can try fn+F5

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately it doesn't work eighter. I select the built-in display, set it to OFF, and after i hit Apply still the monitor shows only the mouse, not the entire desktop. What's the problem??

Comment: fn+F5 is not work?

Comment: No, the display is still black...Maybe it has to do with the 'xrandr' commands?

Comment: are you install NVIDIA graphics drivers

Comment: I don't know if the drivers are installed. How can i find?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeWTSprpq1M  or search google it

Comment: I installed the NVidia driver (after your tutorial), restart, after that it's even worse: now it's not showing the Benq display any more, only the built-in display...I don't know what to do. Seems like Ubuntu has problems over problems, as for me...

Comment: sorry for late reply. now you select your monitor set primary

Comment: off your laptop monitor

Comment: or ithink now work fn+F5 key

Comment: Did you read my last comment? After installing the Nvidia drivers, i cannot see the external monitor inside Display settings. How could i set it as primary if i cannot see it? Also i don't have an option to set as primary. Please, be more specific! Thanks!

Comment: Now Check Nvidia settings

Comment: See my last comment with the attached picture

Answer (score 0):

[image: go to additional drivers and select nvidia binary driver]

go to additional drivers and select nvidia binary driver more information please check this video youtube.com/watch?v=PeWTSprpq1M (Install Nvidia Driver on Ubuntu 16.04 (GUI Method for Beginners))
now you can understand what is x server

then try this video [fix NVIDIA Optimus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nGbWE-pvIE)

or 
 place search "nvidia graphic driver on ubuntu" on google try to fix. Because my knowledge is not enough this question